# c# Windows Forms Application MVC 403 error when creating a download file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have created a MVC site which has a download button ( which invokes a JS Blob file creation).
This works fine in browsers and Mobile devices, 
I am now trying to get it to work from within a c# Windows Forms Application (a very basic Form with a WebBrowser common control added in, pointing to the website).
I needed to add the following code to the HTML so it would open within the App

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

otherwise, it would give me errors when it tried to access the sites js files.
the "blob" code looks like

```
$('.btn-success').click(function () {
                 var CSV = [
                     '"1","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
                     '"2","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
                     '"3","val1","val2","val3","val4"'
                 ].join('\n');

                 window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

                 var contentType = 'text/csv';

                 var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], { type: contentType });

                 var xmlcsv = document.createElement('a');
                 xmlcsv.download = 'XMLtoCSV.csv';
                 xmlcsv.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
                 xmlcsv.textContent = 'Download CSV';

                 xmlcsv.dataset.downloadurl = [contentType, xmlcsv.download, xmlcsv.href].join(':');
                 console.log(xmlcsv);
                 //document.body.appendChild(xmlcsv);
                 xmlcsv.click();
             });
```

when I run it from within the App, I get the follow message when I click the download button

[403 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEvOV.png)

NB: line 430 =     xmlcsv.click();

can anyone advise please ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I got it work by changing the code to

```
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;

var contentType = 'text/csv';

var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], { type: contentType });

window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(csvFile, 'bookingXML.csv'); // Now the user will have the option of clicking the Save button and the Open button.
                 //alert('File save request made using msSaveOrOpenBlob() - note the two "Open" and "Save" buttons below.');

             });
```

Thanks to everyone that helped

Answer (score 0):

Just change the href of your button on click, do not create a new A element, I think this is browser protection against popups.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test download</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="btn-success" download="a.csv" href="#">Download CSV</a>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.btn-success').click(function () {
        var CSV = [
            '"1","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
            '"2","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
            '"3","val1","val2","val3","val4"'
        ].join('\n');

        $(this).attr('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(CSV));
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but if I swap you code for mine (in my HTML and JS files), the button stops working in browsers, and gives me s "Page not found" in the c# app. Is there a value I can substitute ('a') for ? I have been trying to find one, but no luck. thanks again

Comment: Strange, I have tested this code on my chrome, was fine. Is window.open() works in C#?

Comment: I'm fairly new to c#, and Web Forms, so am not sure if windows.open() would work in both Web Forms AND a browser

Comment: Hi @h0x91B,
I believe I got it work by changing the code to
var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;

var contentType = 'text/csv';

var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], { type: contentType });

window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(csvFile, 'bookingXML.csv'); // Now the user will have the option of clicking the Save button and the Open button.
                     //alert('File save request made using msSaveOrOpenBlob() - note the two "Open" and "Save" buttons below.');

                 });
Thanks to everyone that helped

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, this is the code that I am using that (seems)to work for both PC's and Mobile devices.

```
   $('.btn-success').click(function () {
             var CSV = [
                 '"1","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
                 '"2","val1","val2","val3","val4"',
                 '"3","val1","val2","val3","val4"'
             ].join('\n');

                if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

                    var contentType = 'text/csv';

                    var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], { type: contentType });

                    var xmlcsv = document.createElement('a');
                    xmlcsv.download = 'XMLtoCSV.csv';
                    xmlcsv.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
                    xmlcsv.textContent = 'Download CSV';
                    xmlcsv.dataset.downloadurl = [contentType, xmlcsv.download, xmlcsv.href].join(':');
                    console.log(xmlcsv);
                    xmlcsv.click();

                }
                else {
                 var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;
                 var contentType = 'text/csv';
                 var csvFile = new Blob([CSV], { type: contentType });
                 window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(csvFile, 'bookingXML.csv'); // Now the user will have the option of clicking the Save button and the Open button.
                }
             });
```